# search gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

i trying to search gridview but fail,please tell me where i did wrong,or i need include reference?
my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Search_Gridview(strKey, strGV) {
    var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var tblData = document.getElementById(strGV);
    var rowData;
    for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
        rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
        var styleDisplay = 'none';
        for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
            if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                styleDisplay = '';
            else {
                styleDisplay = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
    }
}
```

my gridview

```
<div style="border: 1px solid Black; width: 800px; padding: 20px; height: 350px;
font-size: 20px;">
Search :
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" onkeyup="Search_Gridview(this, 'gvTest')"></asp:TextBox><br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" CellPadding="10" Width="500px">
</asp:GridView>
```

my c# data fill gridview

```
private void FillRoleGrid()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeNo,Name,POsition FROM userInfo"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    gvTest.DataSource = dt;
                    gvTest.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

im totally no idea where i did wrong ,please guide me,thank you.

Comment: We totally have no idea how you failed. If you want the SO community to help you effectively, please provide the details for this `fail` you speak of.

Comment: So as my understanding, There are no issue with gvTest grid view, it has already been filled with data, right ?
If that case, you debug your function Search_Gridview to see if any breakpoints was hit. If it was hitting, then check your logic.
There are not much information from you so it's difficult to give a relevant answer.

Comment: use F12 tools from google chrome to debug your javascript. You will be able find your issue that way.

Comment: i am getting this error 
-- for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++)  "Gridview_Search.aspx:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null"

Answer (score 0):

var strGV = '<%= gvTest.ClientID %>' in javascript.